# Copying files in the same Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, s3cmd

I am trying to copy the entire `/contentstore/` folder on a bucket to a timestamped version. Basically `/contenstore/` would be copied to `/contentstore/20130729/`.

My entire script uses `s3s3mirror` first to clone my production S3 bucket to a backup. I then want to rename the backup to a timestamped copy so that I can keep multiple versions of the same.

I have a working version of this using `s3cmd` but it seems to take an abnormally long time. The `s3s3mirror` part between the two buckets is done within minutes, possibly because it is a refresh on existing folder. But even in the case of a clean `s3s3mirror` (no existing contentstore on backup) it take around 20 minutes.

On the other hand copying the conentstore to a timestamped copy on the backup bucket takes over an hour and 10 minutes.

Am I doing something incorrectly? Should the copy of data on the same bucket take longer than a full clone between two different buckets?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

P.S: The command I am running is `s3cmd --recursive cp backupBucket/contentStore/ backupBucket/20130729/`

Comment: How are you creating the directory 20130729?

Comment: I actually was using 's3cmd --recursive cp backupBucket/contentStore/ backupBucket/20130729/'. Here 'backupBucket' was a variable set to s3://bucketName. Should I be creating the bucket differently?

Comment: I am not sure if this would speed it up or not but have you considered downloading them and then uploading them? the script for that would not be hard

Comment: Unfortunately, downloading and uploading is not an option. I am fairly new to AWS but it baffles me that copy files (mirroring) between two different buckets is quicker than doing that within the same.

Comment: Have you considered ever iterating over a list of everything in your bucket and copying it one at a time? Recursion is more costly in memory, as each recursive call generally requires a memory address to be pushed to the stack - so that later the program could return to that point. Thus it might make it faster and less intense on aws or your computer to iterate over each file instead of accessing it recursively

Answer (score 0):

Since your source path *contains* your destination path, you may actually be copying things more than once -- first into the destination path, and then again when that destination path matches your source prefix. This would also explain why copying to a different bucket is faster than within the same bucket.

If you're using s3s3mirror, use the -v option and you'll see exactly what's getting copied. Does it show the same key being copied multiple times?